# JMeter: What logic would be best to apply if each threadgroup is dependent on previous ones response

Tags: multithreading, csv, jmeter, response

We have 2 thread groups which is dependent on previous ones response.

SIGNUP will generate some  PHONE NUMBER and PASSWORD in response which will be utilized by LOGIN thread group.

I don't want to use CSV and would like to capture response from SIGNUP and use same credentials (PHONE NUMBER and PASSWORD) to execute LOGIN.

Also, which timer would be better to use.

Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and would like to start 2nd one only when some information from 1st one is available the best way to proceed is using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)

It provides a simple [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) queue which is accessible by different threads (even if they reside in different thread groups) so you can simply put these PHONE NUMBER and PASSWORD into the queue and configure 2nd Thread Group to operate only when the credentials are available.

There is [SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/SynchronizationPluginsExample.jmx) test plan which demonstrates sharing cookies between Thread Groups, you can use it as a basis for your implementation.

Inter-Thread Communications plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)